# OnClickListener in Android, no errors but application stops

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have no idea why this code does not working. I have a `TextView` called `text1` and `Button` called `button1`. I want to change the text in `text1` after clicking `button1`.

I noticed that program works when I comment line `button1.setOnClickListener(this);` but consequently nothing happened.

```
 package com.example.testowaniefragmentow;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

        TextView text1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_B1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_text);


            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }

        }

        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {

            }


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
                return rootView;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_B1:
                text1.setText("Text has been changed");
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: your log cat plz, Debug your app and find where your app is crashing

Comment: Button belongs to `fragment_main.xml`. Initialize it in onCreateView `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: is `button_B1` button in the `activity_main.xml` layout or in the `fragment_main.xml` layout?

Comment: That is the problem, button is belongs to fragment and you are finding it from activity. Change it!!!

Answer (score 2):

Change

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

to

`setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`

Hope it helps..

**OR**

as Mike said copy the whole contents of `fragment_main.xml` to `activity_main.xml`..

Comment: You should, rather, direct the OP to move the necessary Views in `fragment_main` to `activity_main`.

Comment: or rather encourage op to use fragments an initialize views in fragments

Comment: I agree, @Lal, that it is the simple solution, but for beginners already confused about the distinction between Activities and Fragments, suggesting this might just add to the confusion later.

Comment: oops sorry @MikeM ..Actually i didn't think of that.. I just needed to solve his problem anyhow..

Comment: @Lal should encourage op to use fragments. Better initialize views in fragments onCreateView

Comment: @Raghunandan, I agree that that everyone should learn Fragments, but for  beginners writing "Hello World" apps, sometimes just a plain Activity is easier to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly defined your TextView. You have two text TextViews in your code. one is in your MainActivity class and the second is local variable for onCreate method. so in your onClicklistener when you try to set the text for text1 it is actually not been initialised. Please change your code in MainActivity class and onCreate method as following and keep everything as same.

```
 //declare the view and button here.
 TextView text1;
 Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //initialise the view and button here but do not declare it again or else they will become local variable
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_B1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_text);


        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro:

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_B1:
            text1.setText("Text has been changed");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        }
    });
```